# Проблема с отправкой запроса через httpie клиент (проблема синтаксиса запросов)

Tags: windows, http, cmd, httpie

Тренируясь по [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/193458/#p4) статье я пытаюсь, подняв локальный сервер с помощью express.js и БД с помощью MongoDB, посылать запросы к своему веб-приложению в консоли через [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie). Для совсем простых по структуре запросов работает.

Но даже в примере, который предлагается на самом [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie#request-url):

```
http www.google.com search=='HTTPie logo' tbm==isch
```

- уже вылетает синтаксическая ошибка. Связана, судя по всему, с синтаксисом аргумента у search:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такие же ошибки, разумеется, происходят и в более сложных запросах:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно ЭТА проблема моим "экспромтом" чинится, если склеить аргументы через "+" (Joe + Doe, например). Но это какая-то ерунда, не описано в документации (если я правильно ищу и правильно понимаю) и, кроме того, всё ещё остаются проблемы с синтаксисом, которые так просто уже не починишь.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём дело? Почему не получается отправить запрос, используя описанный авторами httpie синтаксис? Хотелось бы получить ответ строго по теме, может кто-то тоже использует httpie | json и знает причину.

Comment: P.S. Не смог добавить метку httpie, т.к. нужна репутация.

Answer (score 1):

Примеры написаны в расчёте на POSIX shell, а `cmd.exe` на Windows воспринимает одинарные кавычки по другому. Просто замените их на двойные.

```
c:\> http :8888 search=="HTTPie logo" tbm==isch
```

Это выполнит запрос:

```
c:\> py -mwebbrowser "http://localhost:8888/?search=HTTPie+logo&tbm=isch"
```

Comment: Поправка - `cmd.exe` вообще никак не воспринимает кавычки. На винде каждая программа сама парсит свои аргументы как хочет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov верно—одинарные кавычки всеми игнорируются в данном случае на Винде. Но сперва команду всё-таки cmd видит, иначе внутренние команды типа `dir` и мета-символы типа `^` не работали бы. А только потом python, использует [правила для c/c++ программ (от компилятора зависит), чтобы разбить строчку на аргументы](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULESCHANGE).